# A question about a fractal like iteratively defined function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algorithms, fractals, chaos-theory

I am trying to figure out what the following function $f:\Bbb{R}^3-\{\mathbf{0}\}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined below (in pseudocode) does:

---

**function**  $f(\mathbf{v}\in \Bbb{R}^3-\{\mathbf{0}\})$
{
    $a=b=0;$      $(a,b\in \Bbb{R})$
    **for** ${(i=0; i<I; i=i+1)}$
    {
            $\mathbf{v}=\frac{|\mathbf{v}|}{||\mathbf{v}||^2}-\mathbf{A};$
            $a=a+|||\mathbf{v}||-b|;$
            $b=||\mathbf{v}||;$
    }
    **return** $ a;$
}

Where $I$ is some positive integer that determines the number of iterations the loop will run, and $\mathbf{A}$ is some vector in the set $\{(t,t,t)\in\Bbb{R}^3|t\in[-1,1]\}$.

(The notation $|\mathbf{v}|$ denotes component wise absolute value of the vector elements)

---

I do not know how this function looks like and what it does and I am only interested  in vectors $\mathbf{v}\in[-1,1]^3-\{\mathbf{0}\}$.

Also what is $lim_{\mathbf{v}\to \mathbf{0}}f(v)$?

---

Here are some picks that were generated by my shader (maybe they can help):

When $I = 1$ and $\mathbf{A}$ is any vector in the set $\{(t,t,t)\in\Bbb{R}^3|t\in[-1,1]\}$ the images will be something like this
[image]

As we increase the value of $I$ things get interesting and we get imaged like those:

When $I = 10$ and $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)}$
[image]

When $I = 10$ and $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{(0.63, 0.63, 0.63)}$
[image]

When $I = 10$ and $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{(0.74, 0.74, 0.74)}$
[image]

When $I = 10$ and $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{(1, 1, 1)}$
[image]

Since the center of every image is solid white I can conjecture that $lim_{\mathbf{v}\to\mathbf{0}}f(\mathbf{v})=\infty$

---

the main part of my GLSL fragment shader that produces the images and implements the function $f$ defind above is

```
vec3 color = vec3(0.);
vec3 v = vec3(2 * (TexCoord.xy - .5), 0.); // TexCoord.xy in [0,1]^2
float a = 0.;
float b = 0.;

// The loop that I do not understand
for (uint i = 0U; i < I; i++)
{
    v = abs(v) / dot(v,v) - A;
    a += abs(length(v) - b);
    b = length(v);
}

a = a * a * a; // Adding some contrast

float brightness = 0.015;
color = vec3(.1, .01, .0001) * a * brightness;

FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
```

---

Any help will be appreciated.

(I've encountered this function while trying to achieve some interesting fractal like visual effects while doing graphics programming)

### EDIT

In all pictures, the parameter $Z$ denotes the $Z$ coordinate of the vector $\mathbf{v}$

$I=90$, $A=0$ and $Z=0$
[image]

$I=90$, $A=0.5$ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=90$, $A=1$ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=100$, $A=0$ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=100$, $A=0.5$ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=100$, $A=1$ and $Z=0$
[image]

$I=100$, $A= 0.042373 $ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=100$, $A= 0.906780 $ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=100$, $A= 0.932203 $ and $Z=0$
[image]

$I=100$, $A= 0.046610 $ and $Z= 0.894068 $ (cool dotted effect)
[image]

$I=16$, $A= 0.194915 $ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=29$, $A= 0.194915 $ and $Z=0$
[image]

$I=500$, $A=0$ and $Z=0$
[image]
$I=500$, $A=0.5$ and $Z=0$ (nearly all white)
[image]
$I=500$, $A=1$ and $Z=0$
[image]

$I=1000$, $A=0$ and $Z=0$
[image]

$I=1000$, $A=0.5$ and $Z=0$ (nearly all white)
[image]

$I=1000$, $A=1$ and $Z=0$
[image]

---

Here are some images that view the first iteration of the loop on the xy plane with $A=(0.5,0.5,0)$:

(I will try to generate images for greater iterations)

Above the xy plane view
[image]

Below the xy plane view
[image]

Comment: Nice images, but what do the colours represent? Is black low values and white high values?

Comment: @mathreadler The set fo vectors that I pass to the function are of the form (x,y,0) where x,y∈[-1,1] each mapped to a pixel on the computer screen space.

Comment: By the way, color values on the computer are represented using values in the interval [0,1] (I.e. r,g,b∈[0,1]).

Comment: To make sure I understand. You pick an initial vector $v$, run it through for some number of iterations $I$, and then use the values of $a$ generated for each vector to color a plane?

Comment: @Zach466920 Exactly.

Comment: @MathNerd Then I'll keep working on the 1-d version. I have a feeling what I find there will transfer over to the 3-d case. I'll look at $\lim_{I \to {\infty}} I$ and $\lim_{v_0 \to 0}$. Increasing the number of iterations to infinity, and setting the initial vector to $0$.

Comment: @Zach466920 Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @MathNerd Clearly fractal. What about other values of $A$ around $I=100$? I believe this fractal converges very well so no need for higher $I$. Are many of them fractal? That'd be very interesting.

Comment: I've posted the new images. Now I think that the number of itreration ($I$) simply determines how detailed the fractal will be, and the value of $A$ is the number that determines the fractal's shape. (When I set the $Z$ value to some constant I get additional intersting shapes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel the need to take this to a more mathematical realm. So here's a commentary to long for comments.

**Set-Up**

We have a system of recurrence relations defined by,

$$(1) \quad \vec v_{n+1}={{|\vec v_n|} \over {||\vec v_n||^2}}-\vec A$$
$$(2) \quad a_{n+1}=a_n+| \ ||\vec v_n||-b_n|$$
$$(3) \quad b_{n+1}=||\vec v_n||$$

First let's reduce this to a system of two relations. $(3)$ is redundant, we can simply use $||v_{n+1}||$. We now have,

$$(1) \quad \vec v_{n+1}={{|\vec v_n|} \over {||\vec v_n||^2}}-\vec A$$
$$(4) \quad a_{n+1}=a_n+| \ ||\vec v_n||-||\vec v_{n-1}|| \ |$$

$(1)$ happens to be independent of $(4)$ so I'd suggest that we understand $(1)$ before trying to figure out $(4)$, which is just the picture generator.

**Interpretations**

It may be hard to interpret what $(1)$ and $(4)$ are actually doing. Here's a briefer. $(4)$ is easy. It measures how volatile the path taken from $v_0$ to $v_n$ was. A higher value means the path was longer and more volatile. A lower value means it either didn't have a value explosion, or that it converged to some value. The interpretation of $(1)$ is more subtle. I still don't know exactly what it does, but it seems to normalize the vector to a unit vector, then it does that again, then it subtracts a constant and we start over. Because the vector is normalized, most of the interesting behavior happens in the unit circle around the origin.

**This system is Chaotic**

We can start by constructing a toy model. We'll do this by collapsing $(1)$ to only a recurrence in $1$-d.

$$(5) \quad v_{n+1}={1 \over {|v_n|}}-c$$

Which should retain some of the same characteristics. You seem interested in the case where $v \rightarrow 0$. Using the toy model $(5)$ we see that,

$$v_0=0$$
$$v_1=\infty$$
$$v_2=-c$$
$$v_3={1 \over c}-c$$
$$v_4={1 \over {|{1 \over c}-c|}}-c$$
And so on...

The general behavior of the iterations is very similar to [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). The only difference is the absolute value sign. This changes the behavior dramatically. For instance [here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%2B1%29%3D1%2Fabs%28f%28n%29%29-1%2F2%2C+f%280%29%3D0.7) the behavior of $v_0=0.7$ and $c=0.5$ under iteration.

[image: Figure 1]

The behavior is chaotic. So basically, this toy model shows you why your getting incredibly complex behavior in the $3$-d model. It's the inclusion of the absolute value that's doing it! Compare this to the version without it [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%2B1%29%3D1%2F%28f%28n%29%29-1%2F2%2C+f%280%29%3D0.7).

[image: Figure 2]

Note that it has an explicit formula for the evolution.

**Singularity Analysis**

Let's move to the $2$-d case, equivalent to setting all of the $z$ components to $0$. I'll skip the algebra, but here's the evolution of the vector system.

$$(6) \quad x_{n+1}={{|x_n|} \over {x_n^2+y_n^2}}-v_x$$
$$(7) \quad y_{n+1}={{|y_n|} \over {x_n^2+y_n^2}}-v_y$$

Once again, we'll ignore the detailed analysis of the path indicator function. (I hope to show why that is later). By inspection we can see that the function will become infinite whenever a vector passes through infinity. By inspection
we can see that this happens if the initial components satisfy,

$$x_0^2+y_0^2=0$$

So it really wouldn't be difficult to prove that for the $3$-d case with $z_0$, the same equation must be satisfied. So this answers your question. $\lim_{\vec v \to 0} a_n=\infty$. So the path indicator function becomes infinite. That's why the origin is white in your pictures. The path indicator function also becomes infinite at iteration $n=2$ if,

$$v_x^2 \cdot (x_0^2+y_0^2)+v_y^2 \cdot (x_0^2+y_0^2)+1=2 \cdot v_x \cdot |x_0|+2 \cdot v_y \cdot |y_0|$$

If one could set up a suitable renormalization scheme, it might be possible to find *all* the zeros within some suitable error tolerance.

**Show and Tell**

Here's my attempt at providing pictures. If you wondering about the quality, it was made on a DS. We have a logarithmic path indicator function. It's identical to yours, except I take a log after we're done calculating it. The range of the graphic is the square from $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $-1 \le y \le 1$. Use the origin to base off what the colors mean, as far the path indicator function is concerned.

Below is what results when the constant vector is $v_x=v_y=0.1$.

[image: Figure 3]

Using $v_x=v_y=0.5$, we get qualitatively different behavior.

[image: Figure 4]

Let's add some asymmetry with $v_x=0.25, \ v_y=0$. The line at $y=0$ corresponds to the $1$-D case we discussed above.

[image: Figure 5]

**Fixed and Singularity Points**

So the pictures I posted have very intricate and complex patterns. However, there are two pieces of these pictures that can be readily explained. These are the fixed and singularity points. These values are pretty much what they sound like. Fixed points are points where the path indicator function eventually becomes fixed in value. Singularity points are points where the path indicator function becomes infinite after some iteration. Finding these points becomes very difficult so I'll be only giving an intro to this topic. In the one dimensional case, the recurrence $(5)$ has fixed points at,

$$(8) \pm \cfrac{-c+\sqrt{c^2+4}}{2}$$

If your being keen, you'll notice that the negative solution is false. However, if your very keen you'll notice that the negative solution will evolve to the real fixed point in one iteration. Basically a fixed point of $-2$ is false, but after one iteration, it will become $2$ which is a fixed point.

To find the singularity points, we have to find values such that the iteration becomes infinite. In our case, we can do this by finding values such that the iteration is $0$. If we find these values, we know that the very next value will be infinite. Looking at $(5)$ again, we find that for an initial point $v_0$ to evolve to an infinite point after $1$ iteration, $v_0$ must equal $0$. For, the case of two iterations, we solve,

$$0={1 \over {|v_0|}}-c$$

Which implies that $v_0=\pm {1 \over c}$. We can then move on to finding the values of $v_0$ that give infinite values after three iterations and so forth.

Let's use the third picture for an example. We have $v_x=0.25, \ v_y=0$ so we can our above analysis quite nicely. Using $(8)$ we find the fixed points to be

$$\pm {{\sqrt{65}-1} \over 8}=\pm 0.8828...$$

That corresponds to the dark areas on the $y=0$ line in the third picture. Similarly we can find the first three singularity points to be, $0$, $\pm 4$, and $\pm 4/17=0.235...$. By the way, formulas exist to find the next $6$ singularity points.

There are similar, albeit more complicated, formulas for the two and three dimensional cases. For instance, I provide a formula that can be utilized for finding singularity points in another section.

**Potpourri**

The final interesting thing to note is that the iteration of $v$, in the two dimensional case, can be turned into a complex iteration equivalent to,

$$z_{n+1}=\cfrac{\operatorname{Re}(z_n)+\operatorname{Im}(z_n)}{|z_n|^2}$$

Where we have the real and imaginary part operators involved.

I may or may not add something else...

Comment: Thanks a bunch, This is by far a great explanation.

Comment: From your sequence I can see that the value of $a$ that the function returns is actually the sum of all absolute differences between consecutive elements of the sequence $v_n$.

Comment: I don't know If it helps, But if you want I can send you the source code of a small OpenGL ES iPad app I've built that visualizes this fractal. (It includes Sliders that updates the values of $I$, $A$ and the $Z$ value of the vector $v$, so that the fractal parameters can be changed interactively and the updated faractal is shown on screen immediately) (The app was used to generate the images above).

Comment: @MathNerd I do code, but not very much, not well, and not in a traditional setting, so I wouldn't be able to make much use of it. Thanks for the offer though :) I'll be adding new things to this post sporadically, so just check back over the next couple of days to see where I got. Let me know if you come up with a breakthrough.

Comment: Thanks a bunch again, The images I get with the app can become extermely chaotic and non-predictable (and very interesting), I've thought that if you can view the fractal easily and tweak its parameters interactively it may help you a lot in understanding how it works (If it help, If you want that I'll post an image for some parameters that you want to check please tell me (For example $I=5$ and $A=0.2$)).

Comment: @MathNerd Well that's the thing. I want to see what happens when you take everything to the limit. One usually has to do that analytically first. However, seeing large values of $I$ like $I=100$ vs $I=90$ could help visualize this. As far as the $A$ are concerned, I don't know yet.

Comment: Do you want that I'll post images for any combination of  $I=90,100$ and $A=0,0.5,1$ ?

Comment: @MathNerd That'd be great.

Comment: By the way, The color valus for $r,g,b$ must be in the range $[0,1]$, so if the function produces values greater than $1$, they will be treated as $1$, similarly negative color values will be treated as $0$ (In our case the function retunrs non-negative values so the case for negative values is irrelevant).

Comment: We should probably move this to chat (it'll create a link to follow). I was able to program it. I did make some minor changes though. I use a logarithmic pallet scaled coloring, I eliminate the $z$ component of the process, and have it displayed in  a mosaic form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29809/discussion-between-zach466920-and-mathnerd).

Answer (score 1):

So first out some **theoretical pondering**

When comes to theoretical investigation, since we have considered 2d vectors so far, I will make the simplification to move to $z = r+wi \in \mathbb{C}^1$ where , the operation $|{\bf v}|$ takes $z = r + wi$ to $|r| + |w|i$, i.e.

1. Moves complex number to the first quadrant by a series of reflections in the real and imaginary axes
2. Normalizes it's length.
3. Subtracts a prescribed vector which is **also always in the first quadrant**.

Also, we can modify $\frac{|v|}{\|v\|^2} \rightarrow \frac{|v|+\epsilon}{\|v\|^2+\epsilon}$, to avoid possible issue of having the denominator too close to 0 to cause numerical instability or division by 0.

The rest of the operations do not involve the information of which quadrant we were in any way. Therefore we should be able to perform the inverse operations on $\bf A$ **instead of** forward operations on $\bf v$ each iteration. Then what $a$ does is basically to sum the fluctuations of the length of $\bf v$ over the iterations. The absolute value of this number is the distance in the complex plane to the point $\bf A$. So we measure how fast we swing around $\bf A$ in some sense. The dramatic points light up and the ones who remain at the same distance are dark.

---

Here is my octave implementation. Code can be found at the bottom. It sure does some strange fractal-like thing anyway. But before the code, here's some animations.

I choose the colors as gray scale ( each channel the same ): $\|a\|^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and the plots are on the square $x,y \in \left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]^2$

[image]

Above is for ${\bf A} = \frac{1}{3}[1,1,1]^T$, 25 iterations.

[image]

Above is for ${\bf A} = \frac{1}{2}[1,1,1]^T$, 25 iterations.

[image]

Above is for ${\bf A} = [1,1,1]^T$, 25 iterations.

And here's the Octave code:

> > A = [1;1;1]/8;
> >
> > lRes = 512;
> >
> > %[xs,ys,zs] = >>ndgrid(linspace(-0.5,0.5,lRes),linspace(-0.5,0.5,lRes),linspace(eps,eps,1));
> >
> > [xs,ys,zs] = ndgrid(linspace(-1,1,lRes),linspace(-1,1,lRes),linspace(eps,eps,1));
> >
> > v = [vec(xs)';vec(ys)';vec(zs)']';
> >
> > lIters = 30;
> >
> > a=0; b=0;
> >
> > for i_=1:lIters
> >
> > v = abs(v)./(sum(v.^2,2)) - A';
> >
> > a = a + abs(sum(v.^2,2).^0.5-b);
> >
> > b = sum(v.^2,2).^0.5;
> >
> > lImage = reshape(a(:,:,1),[lRes,lRes]).^0.25;
> >
> > imagesc(lImage); colormap gray; drawnow;
> >
> > end

Comment: Looks cool too, especially the third image ;-)

Comment: I've posted my GLSL shader in the main question.

Comment: I was able to generate some additional cool images by changing the **z** component of the vector **v** and using various other values for **A** and **I** but I guess that this function has some kind of unpredictable chaotic behavior.

Comment: One clear thing about the function is that it symmetrical with respect to x,y and z axis, (I.e. For each input vector $v$, if we replace the x,y or z component with their negations we get the same result). The symmetry is clearly noticeable in the images that me and you posted. Therefore it is enough to understand how this function works in the first 3D octant.

Comment: We can add $+\epsilon$ to both numerator and denominator, or at least to the denominator.

Comment: @mathreader By the way if we apply the function on the vector v=(0.5,0.5,0) with A=(1,1,0) we get in the first iteration that v=(0,0,0) and in the second iteration we do the calculation 0/0 which is undefined, how can we overcome this problem by changing the definition of the function f ?, Maybe we can define 0/0 as infinity, 0 or 1 ?